# Rotating image 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is several questions about how to rotate an image, but I want an animation-like rotating. By an

event (tap) I would like to rotate an image with -5 degree then with 5 degree, but if I write both rotating in

the same function (or eventhandler), the first rotate doesn't appear only the second is visible.

```
$("#imgdiv").on('taphold', function(e){
    //$("#imageID").addClass("swing animated");
    $("#imageID").css({"transition-property":"transform","transition-duration":"2s","transform":"rotate(-5deg)"});
    $("#imageID").css({"transition-property":"transform","transition-duration":"2s","transform":"rotate(5deg)"});
    //$("#imageID").removeClass("swing animated");
});
```

I have also tried a swing animation with classes (addClass, then removeClass), but with the same result:

```
@keyframes swing { 
    25% { transform: rotate(-5deg); } 
    50% { transform: rotate(0deg); } 
    75% { transform: rotate(5deg); } 
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); } 
} 

.swing { 
    transform-origin: top center; 
    animation-name: swing;
}

.animated { 
    animation-duration: 1s;  
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
}
```

Comment: Post you html ,css or make a fiddle to help you better.

Comment: Mind using CSS3 keyframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with addclass and removeclass, but there is one mistake in your code.
you are doing addclass and removeclass at the same time. so, animation is not happening or only one time happens
so try setTimeout:

```
$("#imgdiv").on('click', function(e){
    $("#imageID").addClass("swing animated");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#imageID").removeClass("swing animated");
    },1000)
});
```

i have done that in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tqn394k9/

Answer (score 3):

You may put the second animation in a setTimeout in order to delay its animation until the first one finishes.

You can also put your transition in the css rather than in JS. Just place the transform value in JS.

Try something like this [SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oazwgg1e/2/).

JS:

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
  //animate to -5deg
    $(this).css('transform','rotate(-5deg)');
  //animate to 5deg
    setTimeout(function(){$(".clickme").css('transform','rotate(5deg)')},1000);
  //animate back to root position
 setTimeout(function(){$(".clickme").css('transform','rotate(0deg)')},2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. What if I would like to set the image after the animation to root position (0 degree)?

Comment: The sample does set to root position 0deg. It is included within the function in the setTimeout.

Comment: Sorry, my question was bad. Your code is OK, but it rotates just with -5 degree, then doesn't rotate with 5 degree.

Comment: So when it's clicked you want it to rotate 5 degrees anticlockwise, then 10 clockwise then back to its original position?